# WebGL: Read the contents of a buffer object?

Tags: webgl, vbo, arraybuffer

On other platforms I've kept memory usage down by storing seldom-accessed per-vertex geometry and color data solely in a VBO in GPU memory and using glMap to read and/or modify it piecewise every once in a while.

When reading the OpenGL ES 2 book I noticed it says on page 118:

> OpenGL allows applications to read the contents of the vertex buffer
>   storage but these API calls are missing from OpenGL ES. As there is no
>   mechanism to read buffer data in OpenGL ES, these enums are no longer
>   valid and are therefore not supported.

I Googled around a while and saw the existence of glMapBufferOES (which seems poorly documented).  Does this still work?  Is it a commonly supported extension? Is there any way I can use this in WebGL?  If not, are there other ways I could read the contents of a VBO, or is my only option to keep a Javscript reference to my own ArrayBuffer object (or some other non-GPU storage)?

Answer (score -1):

If an extension is not in [the Khronos WebGL extension repository](http://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/extensions/), then it is not available for use in WebGL.